# Dynamically injecting swfupload.js into a GWT project. JS code is unintentionally called before <span> exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm attempting to inject a [swfupload.js](https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) into a GWT project to support multifile upload. I have a version of the swfupload.js running locally on a non-GWT project but I'm having difficulty integrating it into the GWT project.

I suspect that the JS is being called before the `<span>` element exists in the DOM. The JS script is injected when an upload modal dialog appears, after adding a breakpoint at swfupload.js > loadFlash() and inspecting the `targetElement` it comes back as undefined when it should be the `#btnFileUpload` span. Additionally, I could see the `<span>` on screen when the script stops on the breakpoint.

- With the breakpoint, querying for `$('#btnFileUpload')` in console I
  get `[]`.
- Without the breakpoint, querying for `$('#btnFileUpload')`
  in console I get `<span id="btnFileUpload">...</span>`.

**Script Injector code in GWT/Java** (works to the best of my knowledge)

```
@UiFactory
FormPanel createForm() {

    [...]

    String baseURL = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();
    ScriptInjector.fromUrl(baseURL + "js/jquery.min.js").inject();
    String[] files = { 
        "swfupload.js", 
        "handlers.js", 
        "swfupload.queue.js",
        "fileprogress.js", 
        "swfupload.impl.js"
    };
    for (String file : files) {
        ScriptInjector.fromUrl(baseURL + "js/swfupload/" + file).inject();
    }

   [...]

}
```

**JavaScript: swfupload.impl.js**

```
var swfu;
$('#btnFileUpload').ready(function() {
    var settings = {
        button_placeholder_id: "btnFileUpload"
        [...]
    };
    swfu = new SWFUpload(settings);
}
```

**JavaScript: swfupload.js**

```
// Gets called from SWFUpload 'constructor'
SWFUpload.prototype.loadFlash = function () {
    var targetElement, tempParent;
    [...]
    // Get the element where we will be placing the flash movie
    targetElement = document.getElementById(this.settings.button_placeholder_id) || this.settings.button_placeholder;

    if (targetElement == undefined) {
        throw "Could not find the placeholder element: " + this.settings.button_placeholder_id;
    }
    [...]
};
```

*Note: I know there is an implentation of SWFUpload for GWT but I'd rather not go that route.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ScriptInjector` the scripts get added to the page using an `IFrame` so your scripts are running within their own browsing context. The `document.getElementById` in `swfupload.js` is accessing it's "own DOM" rather than the top-level one. You can try accessing the parent context, that probably has the `span` you're looking for, by using `window.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for loading multiple js into GWT

```
   ScriptInjector.fromUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "lodash.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
            .setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
                    System.out.println("lodash loading failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    System.out.println("lodash loaded");
                }
            }).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "jquery.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
            .setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
                    System.out.println("jquery loading failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    System.out.println("jquery loaded");
                }
            }).inject();
    ScriptInjector.fromUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "backbone.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
            .setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
                    System.out.println("backbone loading failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    System.out.println("backbone loaded");
                }
            }).inject();

    ScriptInjector.fromUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "joint.min.js").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
            .setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
                    System.out.println("joint.min loading failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                    System.out.println("joint.min loaded");
                }
            }).inject();
```